# @media query used inline for use within email?

Tags: html, css, email, media

I'm building an HTML Email, and would like to use @media query to display one banner for mobile and another for desktop/webmail screens. I know most email clients strip out the css found in the  tag. Is there a way to put the css inline? Here's an example of the code in  currently..

```
<style type="text/css">

  @media (max-width: 1000px){
    /* rules defined inside here are only applied to browsers that support CSS media queries and the browser window is 480px or smaller */
    img#standardBanner{display:none !important}
    img#mobileBanner{display:block !important} 
  }

</style>
```

Also is there any other way to be able to do this? I'm not having too much luck.

Thanks!

Comment: this is a little bit confusing ... are you looking for a way to change a banner size depending on client's browser being mobile or desktop?

Comment: basically, i have 2 banners and I want a different one to display based on the width of the browser. so if it's greater than 1000px display standardBanner, if it's less than 1000px display mobileBanner. 1000px is just a random number at this point. Sorry for the lack of clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">

    img#standardBanner{display:block !important}
    img#mobileBanner{display:none !important} 

    @media (max-width: 1000px){

    img#standardBanner{display:none !important}
    img#mobileBanner{display:block !important} 
  }

</style>
```

Comment: You don't want to include any JavaScript in an HTML email. JS is one of the first things that is flagged by SPAM filters as a potential threat.

Comment: yes unfortunately JS will get stripped out, so I'm trying to find a solution using CSS

Comment: true ... updated answer ... see if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: ahh you are right, however, Gmail ignores display:none when placed as an inline style, and marking !important you are unable to override

Comment: can't you use the css property "visibility" instead?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, for a pure css solution the answer would be no it is not possible.

You could though serve the images from a server and use a scripting language like PHP to get the device information of the user and then serve the appropriate image based on that using PHP function header.